# Mistake - sudo chown -Rh not-root-user /

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server, chown

Well that. Made a terrible mistake on ubuntu server 18.04 (production server) and ran

```
 chown -Rh some-not-root-user /
```

Now `sudo` is not working. Is there any way to reverse this?

Comment: Assuming you mean `chown -Rh`... no there's no easy way to revert that. You can change ownerships back to root using a live CD, but there are a LOT of directories and files that can't be owned by root.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/987531/693277

Comment: Thanks. Bot answers are useful.